# Como exibir o ultimo registro armazenado no banco de dados mysql em uma interface Swing do Java?

Tags: java, mysql, swing

Eu quero exibir na interface gráfica do java swing o numero total de usuários cadastrados lá no meu banco de dados
olhem o que eu tentei

Ele da erro null

```
    public void restt() {
        String sql = "select count(id) from login";
        try {

            pst = conexao.prepareStatement(sql);
            Long quantidade = rs.getLong(1);
            resu.setEnabled(false);
            resu.setText(String.valueOf(quantidade));
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Obrigado pela atenção, peço a vossa ajuda.

Comment: "*o numero total de usuarios*" já tentou usar um `select count(id)`? mas isso não tem nada a ver com o titulo da pergunta, edite e deixe mais claro o que realmente quer

Comment: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog está dentro do bloco de catch (quando uma exceção ocorre). Isso não está errado?

Comment: Olá Matheus, 
Observando o seu código eu notei que está faltando criar o resultset (rs) usado. Para isso você pode adicionar uma linha depois de declarar o pst com o seguinte código "ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();"

Answer (score 0):

Olá, para ajudar melhor a gente precisa saber qual a linha que dá "null" (NullPointerException?). Vou comentar seu código onde pode haver esse tipo de exceção:

```
public void restt() {
String sql = "select id from login order by id desc limit 1;";
try {
    // conexao não está inicializada nesse escopo, 
    // se não estiver em outro lugar, vai lançar exceção
    pst = conexao.prepareStatement(sql); 

    // rs não está definido nesse escopo, 
    // se não estiver em outro lugar, vai lançar exceção
    String nome = rs.getString(1);

    // resu nesta linha e na próxima também não está inicializado nesse escopo, 
    // se não estiver em outro lugar, vai lançar exceção
    resu.setEnabled(false); 
    resu.setText(nome);
     
} catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Como eu vou fazer iss0

Comment: @MatheusHernández quando vocẽ disse que dá "null", como vocẽ sabe? Provavelmente você viu uma tela com erro. Copie esse erro e mostre pra gente